# How to migrate an Azure 'Backup vault classis" to 'Recovery Services vault'?

Tags: azure, backup, recovery, azure-site-recovery

I've setup an Azure Backup vault some time ago and made backups of my systems to it. The backup vault is of type 'Backup vault (classic)'

Now there is a new kind of Azure Backup vault that enables alert among other options. I need to make use of that options.

How can I migrate the classic vault (which contains a lot of historical information) to the new vault type (Recovery Services Vault)?

I cannot find any option in the portal, nor can I find a Powershell script to execute the migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfournately, it's not possible to do that.

> **Can I migrate a Backup vault to a Recovery Services vault?**
>
> Unfortunately no, at this time you can't migrate the contents of a
>   Backup vault to a Recovery Services vault. We are working on adding
>   this functionality, but it is not currently available.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-backup-faq

It's better wait for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can upgrade a Backup vault to a Recovery Services vault. The upgrade process doesn't impact any running backup jobs, and no backup data is lost. The primary reasons to upgrade a Backup vault to a Recovery Services vault:

•All features of a Backup vault are retained in a Recovery Services vault.

•Recovery Services vaults have more features than Backup vaults, including: 
better security, integrated monitoring, faster restores and item-level restores.

•Manage backup items from an improved, simplified portal.

•New features only apply to Recovery Services vaults.

For more information refer: [Upgrade a Backup vault to a Recovery Services vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-upgrade-backup-to-recovery-services)